# How to get a random integer in given boundaries equal to a given number with a given chance?

Tags: c#, math, random, probability

I need a function like

```
int f(int min, int max, int x, int chance)
// where accepted chance values are 0 to 100 and x values are min to max
```

to return a random integer equal or greater than `min`, smaller or equal to `max` with `chance`% probability of the result to equal `x` and `100-chance`% probability spread uniformly among all other results in the given range.

My solution is to create an array of 100 cells, fill it with random domain-compliant non-`x`-equal numbers, throw-in `chance` number of `x`-equal values and take a value of a random cell. But I believe there is to be a much better solution a better educated developer can suggest. Can you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Random r = new Random();
if (r.Next(100) >= chance)
    return x;
var tmp = r.Next(min, max); // take one less than max to "exclude" x
if (tmp >= x)               // shift up one step if larger than or equal to the exceluded value
    return tmp + 1;
return tmp;
```

Might be an offset by one error somewhere

Comment: @Richard, then `max` would never be returned and `x + 1` would have double chance compared to the rest `!= x` values.

Comment: ah, I understand it now (deleting my comment).  You've got what looks to be the best approach.

Comment: @albin-sunnanbo, the solution is cool, very creative, IMHO, but would you be so kind to explain about "an offset by one error" I can't see what do you mean :-(

Comment: @Ivan, I mean I haven't thought everything through, could be something like `tmp >= x` instead of `tmp >= x - 1` or similar. I can't spot any such errors, I just have not thought carefully about every detail.

Answer (score 4):

One way you could handle this is to do:

```
Random random = new Random();

int f(int min, int max, int x, int chance)
{
    if (random.Next(100) < chance) 
    {
        return x;
    } else { 
        int result = random.Next(min, max + 1);
        while (result == x) {
            result = random.Next(min, max + 1);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Slightly nondeterministic in that you could theoretically get stuck repeating x as your random number, but in practical usage not a problem.

EDIT:  If you look at Albin Sunnanbo's approach, however, he manages to avoid repeated random.Next invocations simply by avoiding the maximum value and incrementing if the first random is x or more (thus also excluding x).

Answer (score 1):

```
static Random r = new Random();

int f(int min, int max, int x, int chance)
{
    if (r.Next(100) < chance) return x;
    else 
    {
        int a;
        do { a = r.Next(min, max + 1); } while (a == x);
        return a;
    }   
}
```

Comment: @Richard: By that comment you mean that you can return x in the second return statement, thus incorrectly increasing the probability of returning x.

Comment: @aaaa bbbb You're right, I mean that you can return x in the second return statement.  This would be incorrect; according to the original question, if (100 - chance)% of the time X should not be returned.

Comment: @Alexandre C Yes, fixed.  Why did you make a a double, though, instead of an int?

Comment: @Richard: oops, I did this out of habit :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work good for you:

```
public int f(int min, int max, int x, int chance)
{
    if (x < min || x > max)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("x must be inbetween min and max");
    }

    var random = new Random();

    //generate a random number between 1 and 100, if it is less than the value of
    //chance then we will return x
    if (random.Next(1, 100) <= chance)
    {
        return x;
    }

    return random.Next(min, max);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, because you may end up returning x out of the second random statement, which is incorrect according to the original question.

Comment: @Richard: By that comment you mean that you can return x in the second return statement, thus incorrectly increasing the probability of returning x